# If $\Lambda \cap U$ is Zariski-dense in $U$, then $\Lambda$ contains $U(k\mathbb Z)$ for some $k ≥ 1$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-groups, linear-groups, chevalley-groups

If $G$ is a $\mathbb Q$-defined subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$, $\Lambda$ is a subgroup of $G(\mathbb Z)$, and $U$ is a unipotent subgroup of $G(\mathbb C)$ such that $\Lambda \cap U$ is Zariski-dense in $U$, why must $\Lambda$ contain $U(k\mathbb Z)$ (the principal congruence subgroup of $U(\mathbb Z)$ of level $k$) for some $k \ge 1$?

This is a bit of generalization of a line I did not understand in the article [Meiri - Generating pairs for finite index subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}(n, \mathbb Z)$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07798) (*page 4, second paragraph*), that I'm trying to expand to the Chevalley groups.

Comment: Cross-post of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3301043/

Comment: This amounts to showing that in a unipotent $\mathbf{Q}$-group (a) no infinite index subgroup is Zariski-dense (b) every finite index subgroup contains a congruence kernel.

Comment: In addition to @YCor's important comment, that you should not cross-post simultaneously on MO and MSE, please also note the less important comment that you should not abuse math mode to italicise $like$ $this$ (`$like$ $this$`).  Instead, you can use asterisks *like this* (`*like this*`).  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'll be careful next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this answer i will follow Yves' comment and add references. If $U = \mathbf{U}(R)$ with $\mathbf U$ an algebraic unipotent $\mathbb Q$-group then the two following facts hold :

- If $\Lambda \le U$ is Zariski-dense subgroup then $U/\Lambda$ is compact (Theorem 2.1 in Raghunathan's book *Discrete subgroups of Lie groups*).
- If $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2 \le \mathbf U(\mathbb Q)$ are both cocompact then $\Lambda_1 \cap \Lambda_2$ has finite index in both (this is true for abelian $U$ and any subset generating the abelianisation generates a cocompact subgroup).

Together these imply that for any $\mathbf U, \Lambda$ as in your question the subgroup $\mathbf U(\mathbb Z) \cap \Lambda$ has finite index in $\mathbf U(\mathbb Z)$. Then the (positive) answer to your question follows from the congruence subgroup property for unipotent groups : any finite-index subgroup of $\mathbf U(\mathbb Z)$ contains a subgroup of the form $\mathbf U(k\mathbb Z)$.

That the latter holds can be proven by elementary means (let me give a sketch : this is true if $U$ is abelian, and if $\Lambda/[\Lambda, \Lambda]$ containes the image of $\mathbf U(k\mathbb Z)$ in the abelianisation then $\Lambda$ should contain $\mathbf U(k^r\mathbb Z)$ where $r$ is the step of $U$). Or you can probably adapt the proof in the case of upper triangular matrices given in B. Sury's book (*The congruence subgroup problem--an elementary approach aimed at applications*, Theorem 2-5.2) to the general unipotent case.

Comment: Thanks! by the way, if I assume $G$ to be a Chevalley group over $\mathbb C$ and $U$ is the unipotent radical of the Borel subgroup, can I assume $U(\mathbb R)$ is abelian?

Comment: also, I'll be happy for a source for the second point for $Λ_1∩Λ_2$ having a finite index.

Comment: Re: your first question, no, for example the unipotent radical of upper triangular matrices (the Borel subgroup of $SL_n$) is not abelian for $n \ge 3$; in fact I think only finitely many split simple groups have a Borel subgroup which is abelian.

Comment: Re: your second question, i did not find an explicit statement to this effect in Raghunathan but the argument I sketched should work (assume that $U$ is simply connected so it is obtained by successive extensions of vector spaces, and do a recursion on the dimension).

Comment: since $Λ∩U≤U(\mathbb Z)$ and cocompact in $U(\mathbb R)$(from your first point) can't I say that $Λ∩U$ is a lattice in $U(\mathbb R)$? then I could use *lemma 2.1.11. (2) in this article* https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186939797188X without the assumption that $U$ is abelian.

Comment: I don't see why not, though you should probably cite Raghunathan for that (which is the source used by Oh).